# How can I customize Validity JS Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am using the following script:

http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm

This is the sample script I am using:

```
    <head>
        <title>Simple</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="jquery.validity.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validity.js"></script>

<script>
        $(function() {
            $("form").validity(function() {
                $("#quantity")
                    .require()
                    .match("number");
            });    
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="">
        <input type="text" id="quantity" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is fine but now when I want to customize what the message says and what it looks like, I am stuck.

The jquery.validity.js is the file where this change is made and I was able to locate the snippet that I can customize, which is available on lines 91-95:

```
// Built-in set of default error messages (for use when a message isn't 
// specified):
messages:{

    require:"<div style='font-size:25px;'>#{field} is required.</div>",
```

Now how can I show this error message next to each input field and how can i customize the message that is shown different per field?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is on [the very same page you linked us to](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm#BasicFunctions). Did you even look?

```
// A specific error message is attached to a specific input.
$("#ssn").require("Your Social Security Number is required to proceed.");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did review but didnt' realize i was missing a file.  HOw do I show the error for a select menu? i looked over the guide and found this:     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() { 
                $("form").validity("input:text, select");
            });
        </script>

Comment: but not sure how to customize it with my select ids... any help? Thanks!

Comment: I've never used this function but I suspect that you just give the selectbox an id or a class so that you can target it: 
`$(".mySelect").require("You must provide a selection.");`